# how to set size of integer fields value limit in migration file laravel 9

Tags: php, mysql, laravel, migration, laravel-8

how to set size of integer fields value limit in migration file of Laravel (7,8,9).

I am trying this code. but it's not work

```
        $table->id();
        $table->string('name');
        $table->integer('ISBN_no',15);
```

Comment: "It doesn't work" Well, _what_ isn't working? Tell us what you want to do, show what you tried, and show what the results were. [Edit] your question and provide all of this in the question. If you have not already done so, take the [tour] to get a feel for how SE sites work.

Answer (score 1):

You can't do this, but you can use different types of integer as shown bellow:

`$table->tinyInteger()`
`$table->smallInteger()`
`$table->integer()`
`$table->mediumInteger()`
`$table->bigInteger()`